# Return multiple HtmlGenericControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vba

I created a function in a class MyClass. This feature is intended to include stylesheets and js code:

```
Public Function myfunction() As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim bootstrapmin As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
        bootstrapmin.Attributes("href") = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        Return bootstrapmin
End Function
```

So far everything is working, actually in the source code is included JavaScript code. My problem is: How can I make sure that Myfunction () includes multiple stylesheets/javascript code?

This way does not work:

```
Public Function test3() As HtmlGenericControl
         Dim bootstrapmin As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
            bootstrapmin.Attributes("src") = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            Return bootstrapmin

     Dim bootstrap As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
            bootstrap.Attributes("src") = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"
            Return bootstrap
        End Function
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can nest **HtmlGenericControl** inside other **HtmlGenericControl**.

If you plan to render those JavaScripts at the bottom of a page, you can place it inside div tag.

```
Public Function test3() As HtmlGenericControl
    Dim div = New HtmlGenericControl("div")

    Dim bootstrapmin = New HtmlGenericControl("script")
    bootstrapmin.Attributes("src") = 
       "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    div.Controls.Add(bootstrapmin)

    Dim bootstrap = New HtmlGenericControl("script")
    bootstrap.Attributes("src") = 
       "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"
    div.Controls.Add(bootstrapmin)

    Return div
End Function
```

***FYI:*** If you plan to render inside header tag, you do not want to place them inside div. Then you will have to call that method twice.